# Word describing a word ending with "-tion"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, nouns

If it exists, what is a/the word describing a word ending with "-tion" (e.g. execution, exemption, perdition, definition, proposition, etc.)?

> "A word ending with '-tion' is called a(n) __."

Comment: Is there a word for any other group of words that end in any other set of letters? I doubt you will do better than *noun*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all Abstract nouns. They are mostly derived (probably via French) from Latin third declension nouns, mostly derived in turn from third conjugation verbs.

Comment: "Cation" is an abstract noun?

Comment: Caution end in -tion; Cation ends in -ion.